# concatenate cmd line starting from some parameter

Tags: bash, string, parameters

If I get a cmd line like:

```
myscript param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6 ... (so on)
```

How can I save a string consisting of parameters starting from some specific one?
The $@ gives me the whole command line concatenated. What I need is to get a string starting like "param4 param5 param6 ... (so on)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take aways the uninteresting arguments by:

```
shift 3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variant on array slicing to do this:

```
args1to3="${*:1:3}"  # Three arguments starting from $1
args4on="${*:4}"     # The arguments starting from $4
```

BTW, this may not be what you want, because it just sticks the arguments together with spaces between them; if any of the arguments also *contain* spaces, it'll lose track of which spaces were inside arguments and which were between them (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).  If you want to be able to keep them straight, use an array instead:

```
args1to3=("${@:1:3}")   # Three arguments starting from $1, as an array
args4on=("${@:4}")      # The arguments starting from $4, as an array

othercmd "${args1to3[@]}"             # Pass the first 3 arguments intact
for somearg in "${args4on[@]}"; do    # Process args 4 on, one at a time
  othercmd2 "$somearg"
done
```